Opening QDockWidget Closes Previous QDockWidget on Ubuntu
I wrote a PyQt5 program using QDockWidgets on Windows.  Selecting items in a QList in the central widget causes a widget to be placed in the right docking area that allows me to edit that item and as I select different items in the QList the widget gets replaced.  If I move the dock widget out into a floating widget or a different dock area and then select a new item then the right dock area gets a new widget and the dock widget I popped out remains.  This is exactly the behavior I want.
I then ran this program on Ubuntu and if I move the dock widget into a floating widget then select a new item  this causes the floating dock widget to dissapear.  If I move the dock widget into a different dock and leave it there or move it into a floating dock then it will persist just like it did on windows.

I was maintaining a list of dock widgets and their dock locations and every time I opened a new dock widget I looked for widgets in the right docking area and deleted them.  I maintained this list with a subclass of QDockWidget that listened to dockLocationChanged to track changing dock locations.  On Ubuntu it looks like this signal doesn't fire when transitioning from docked to floating.  So in my database of dock widgets -> dock area any widgets that got popped out of the right area were listed as being docked in the right area and got deleted when I selected a new item in the list.
I fixed it like so:
DOCK_AREAS = {
 'right': Qt.DockWidgetArea.RightDockWidgetArea,
 'left': Qt.DockWidgetArea.LeftDockWidgetArea,
 'top': Qt.DockWidgetArea.TopDockWidgetArea,
 'bottom': Qt.DockWidgetArea.BottomDockWidgetArea,
 '': Qt.DockWidgetArea.NoDockWidgetArea
}

INVERSE_DOCK_AREAS = {v[1]: v[0] for v in DOCK_AREAS.items()}
...SNIP...
     def on_dock(area):
       text = INVERSE_DOCK_AREAS.get(area, '')
       self.config['dock_area'] = text
+
+    def on_float(floating):
+      if floating:
+        on_dock(Qt.DockWidgetArea.NoDockWidgetArea)
+
     self.dockLocationChanged.connect(on_dock)
+    self.topLevelChanged.connect(on_float)


Sorry but right now both your question and this answer are unclear, and the code you're providing is completely out of context, so it's difficult to understand why it should work. Please edit your question and provide a proper [mre], so that we could really understand (and possibly check on our own) your problem, otherwise none of what you're writing would be helpful to anybody except you.
